# consulta e actualización y librerias

Tags: netbeans

Hola amigos del foro esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien de salud, he terminado mi proyecto en netbeans, les cuento que lo realice a través del netbeans 8.2 y lo quise instalar en otro equipo y me presento problemas, cpon las librerias, pluggins y al tratar de actualizarlo seimpre presentaba problemas y averiguando este ya no corre más y cambio a netbeans.apache, por lo cual averiguando a través e la web y de la misma pagina que es recomendable actualizar por uno más moderno como el netbeans 12.0, ahora mi consulta es la siguiente, al actualizarlo e instalar la versión 12.0 me presentará algunos problemas por las librerías que uno utiliza y el código en si que utiliza actualmente, favor de ayudarme con esta interrogativa que se me presenta, ya que no quiero tener problemas con la actualización y perder todo lo hecho, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: netbeans es una ide... ningun proyecto deberia romperse por cambiar de ide.... Ahora... tu proyecto siempre va a estar como vos queres... probaste abrirlo en la nueva ide?

Comment: @gbianchi no lo he probado ya que tengo miedo de que haya problemas, ya sea con  las librerías y el código

Comment: y hace una copia y probalo.. que impide que pruebes una copia?

Comment: @gbianchi muy buenos días, te comento que ayer realice la prueba de instalar el netbeans 12.0, lo cual tuve que actualizar todas las librerías que utilizó una por una, después actualizar los pluggins, posteriormente las librerías del mismo netbeans 12.0, ahora revisare los códigos pantalla por pantalla, es un trabajo tedioso pero hay que hacerlo cuando uno actualiza, siempre pasa lo mismo, pero al mal tiempo buena cara